# Vue3 documentation example codeblocks are strange

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuejs3

All throughout the Vue 3's documentation, they do the following when showing example code in a component:

```
Vue.createApp({})
```

I've never had to do this though, I simply use

```html
<script>
  export default {
    name: 'example-component-xd'
  }
</script>
```

What am I missing here? I just started learning Vue 3, and I haven't learnt any other versions of Vue before. This question is more just a curiosity I have, as it doesn't impact my ability to understand the documentation, but I thought that it may have something to do with the history of Vue, ES6 or best practices etc. Here is another example:

[image: example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Vue 3, `Vue.createApp({})` replaces `new Vue({})` from Vue 2. This line of code is typically in your entry file, where you mount the app (not in your component files).

The code in the `<script>` tag you showed is for [single file components](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/single-file-component.html), and you can continue using that style. Never would you use `Vue.createApp()` or `new Vue()` in those single file components.

You can checkout an [example Vue 3 app](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-3) that shows `Vue.createApp()` in [`src/main.js`](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-3?file=/src/main.js), while the single file components in [`src/components`](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-3?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue) use the Options API that you're also using.

Comment: Oh, the vue cli boilerplate still uses Vue 2 I think then, that's why there was the discrepancy between the boilerplate code and the docs. Is there a way to use vue cli with Vue 3?

Comment: Yes, the latest version of Vue CLI can generate either version.